# Outlook/Word Autoformats VBA Generated Email

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to generate and then preview an email using an Excel macro. Essentially, I am creating a new `MailItem` with `CreateItem(0)`, setting the `HTMLBody` property, then calling `myemail.Display`. `myemail.Display` opens up the email in Outlook's inspector, which, AFAIK, first runs the email through some sort of Microsoft Word parser, which strips much of the formatting. If instead of calling `myemail.Display` I just call `myemail.Send`, the email is formatted properly, but in this use case we really want to be able to preview the email first.

The particular formatting that is being stripped is that all left-aligned text is being centered. It's not a huge deal, but it would be good if I could understand this behavior. Some potential solutions/answers could include:
1. How to format the HTML so that Word doesn't strip the formatting
2. How to turn off the Word parser engine entirely
3. How to turn off Word auto centering of text

The most promising thing I tried was making a left aligned table, however Outlook/Word added an extra ugly two empty lines after the table. Many solutions look mostly good, but the whole point of formatting/previewing this is because the email is being sent out to important people so I want it to look as good as possible.

Here is an example where Outlook/Word will auto center this text

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
   .To = "someemail@email.com"
   .BCC = ""
   .Subject = "a subjhect"
   .SentOnBehalfOfName = "anotheremail@email.com"
   .HTMLBody = "here is some text that will be auto centered"
   .Display
End With
```

Comment: I have never experienced this issue. Can you share the exact string that you are using for ".HTMLBody"

Comment: Word does not format centered by default. Formatting in Word is controlled by *styles*. It sounds as if the Normal style in the template being applied to the email has been change to be centered. I'm not an Outlook expert, so am not really sure how to find and edit this template, I just remember there is (since a few Office versions) a separate one for emails. Researching that might get you a step further if no Outlook people jump in here. Or ask about how to find it in an end-user forum.

Comment: The template that controls styling in Outlook is NormalEmail.dotm. Typically it can be found in C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates. To edit this template 1) close Outlook, 2) open the template in Word, 3) save the changes to the template, 4) open Outlook and create a new message. The changes you make will not be applied to existing messages or drafts.

Comment: As an example, if you use `.HTMLBody = "<html><body><p align=""left"">here is some text that will be auto centered</p></body></html>"` then, at least in my Outlook (and if you're computer is slow), you can actually see that the email will start out left aligned and then the text will be centered. Another thing to note is that if you don't call .Display and instead just call .Send the email will be formatted properly. Another thing is that if you create a template, add some right or left aligned text, then call `.CreateItemFromTemplate(myTemplte)`  then `.Display`, Outlook will center the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your .HTMLBody doesn't actually contain any HTML currently.  HTML emails are parsed differently by various rendering engines, so the actual subset of HTML you can use across the board can be a case of trial-and-error to determine.

But for something like a simple left-align, it shouldn't be too involved.

Perhaps something like:

`.HTMLBody = "<html><body><p align="left">here is some text that will be auto centered</p></body></html>"`

I guess my point is, the centering isn't coming from your code, except possibly by omission.  The lack of formatting markup is leaving it to the rendering engine to decide how best to display it.

Based on your subsequent comment, I'd suggest sticking with tables (they're generally the most reliable way to format HTML emails in my experience) but you may need to add some Outlook-specific CSS in your document HEAD to sort out the extra spacing:

```
/* Stop Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */

    table,
    td {
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
    }
```

If that's helpful, you can find the above (and further tips) at [ContactMonkey](https://www.contactmonkey.com/blog/outlook-rendering-issues)

Comment: While I was trying to get this to work there was actual HTML in the HTMLBody. I didn't put any in the question itself because I had tried many different things and I wasn't able to get any of them to work, and there is no necessity to use HTML for this particular part of the email. Align="left" was one of the first things I tried. As I said, the only thing that came close to working was using a left aligned table, but extra newlines were added after that, so that wasn't great either.